# Explanation "$ (yA=0 \Rightarrow yb=0) \Rightarrow Cb=0 $" where $CA$ is an all-zero matrix (Schrijver corollary 3.1b)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm missing to understand the following implication from Schrijver's *Theory of Linear and Integer Programming*, corollary 3.1b
$$ (yA=0 \Rightarrow yb=0) \Rightarrow Cb=0 $$

The notation is standard: $A,C$ are matrices and $y,b,z$ are vectors. Vector spaces are assumed finite-dimensional. No other particular assumptions are made.

I'll report the corollary statement and its proof for completeness.

> **Corollary 3.1b** The system $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $yb =0$ for each vector $y$ with $yA = 0$.

> *Proof.* Necessity is trivial, as $yb = yAx = 0$ whenever $Ax=b$ and $yA = 0$. To see sufficiency, let $ L:= \{ z | Ax = z \text{ for some } x \} $. By Theorem 3.1 there exists a matrix $C$ such that $L = \{z | Cz = 0 \}$. Hence $CA$ is an all-zero matrix. Therefore $ (yA = 0 \Rightarrow yb=0) \Rightarrow Cb = 0 \Rightarrow b \in L \Rightarrow \exists x: Ax=b $.

The statement "Hence $CA$ is an all-zero matrix" seems the key, but I don't understand how that implies $Cb = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is indeed $CA = 0$. Namely, consider the assumption
$$
yA = 0 \implies yb = 0
$$
Basically, the idea is to take $y$ to be a row of $C$ [denote the rows of $C$ by $c_i$]. If we do this, we then see
$$
0 = CA = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{bmatrix} A = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 A \\ \vdots \\ c_nA \end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence, $c_i A = 0$ so that $c_i b =0$ as well by assumption. Thus,
$$
Cb = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 b \\ \vdots \\ c_n b \end{bmatrix} = 0
$$